# Integrating Octave in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, octave

I have a code written for displaying 2D histogram in Octave. I want to build a nice GUI for displaying the demo for the code. I thought of using VB forms (using VS2012) for building this. However I could not call the Octave programs from VB. Can anyone give me some ideas regarding this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio distribution of Octave 3.6.2 for Windows includes some basic UI functionality, which may be enough for your needs, so that you could do it all in Octave without having to get Octave and VB to talk to each other. From [Summary of important user-visible changes for version 3.6](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-3.6.html):

> ** The following Matlab-compatible handle graphics functions have
>   been
>       added:
>
> ```
>   guidata         uipanel        uitoolbar
>   guihandles      uipushtool     uiwait
>   uicontextmenu   uiresume       waitfor
>   uicontrol       uitoggletool
> ```
>
> The uiXXX functions above are experimental.
>
> Except for uiwait and uiresume, the uiXXX functions are not
>       supported with the FLTK+OpenGL graphics toolkit.
>
> The gnuplot graphics toolkit does not support any of the uiXXX
>       functions nor the waitfor function.

3.6.4 is also out (see http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/Octave%203.6.4%20for%20Windows%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio/), but I don't know if the UI functionality has been improved or not.

Comment: it's unlikely that there's been improvements of those between 3.6.2 and 3.6.4. The last number of the version number is for minor releases where only regressions and bug fixes are accepted. Even if such improvement was made in the _time between_ those two releases, it would go into the development version, but not merged in the 3.6.X series.